# AttributeModifier Model being encoded

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-6

I'm having a problem with the URL I'm creating for an esi:include using an AttributeModifier. When the URL is rendered on the page, it is getting encoded.

```
WebMarkupContainer esiSrc = new WebMarkupContainer("esiSrc");
String esiUrl = "http://domain.tld/blah/that?param1=abc&param2=123";
esiSrc.add(new AttributeModifier("src", new Model<string>(esiUrl)));
esiSrc.setEscapeModelStrings(false);

add(esiSrc);
```

HTML:
    `<esi:include wicket:id="esiSrc" ttl="12h" onerror="continue" />`

The rendered output is:
    `<esi:include ttl="12h" onerror="continue" src="http://domain.tld/blah/that/?param1=abc&amp;param2=123" />`

Any suggestions?

Comment: In HTML all & in attributes have to be encoded, to ensure valid entity parsing. Who says that should be different for esi:include?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/ticket/413 you're looking for the wrong solution.

Comment: Was told that we had to fix issue on our end.